# Jackson automatically expect string started by numbers as integer

Tags: java, jackson

If you run such a test

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper2 = new ObjectMapper();

    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addDeserializer(TestClass.class, new TestClassDeserializer());
    mapper2.registerModule(module);

    TestClass testClass = mapper2.readValue("5 ttt", TestClass.class);

    System.out.println(testClass.field);
}

private static class TestClassDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<TestClass> {
    @Override
    public TestClass deserialize(final JsonParser p, final DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        TestClass param = new TestClass();
        param.field = p.getValueAsString();
        return param;
    }
}

public static class TestClass {
    public String field;

    public TestClass() {
    }

    public TestClass(final String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
}
```

You will get "5" in result:

I cant understand why jackson think that "5 ttt" is a integer, and is it possible to disable such behavior?

P.S. (Thanks Diego Borba for idea, but unfortunately it also does not work)

If i add deserializer for field, like this

```
public static class TestClass {
    @JsonDeserialize(using = TestClassDeserializerForInsideField.class)
    public String field;

    public TestClass() {
    }

    public TestClass(final String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
}
```

and add deserializer for field:

```
public class TestClassDeserializerForInsideField extends JsonDeserializer {
    @Override
    public Object deserialize(final JsonParser p, final DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        final String valueAsString = p.getValueAsString();
        return valueAsString;
    }
}
```

This will not work. I need to make object `TestClass` from just a string "5 ttt". So, if i remove module deserializer (`TestClassDeserializer`), than jackson can't understand how to parse input string (in which object) and throw an exception `MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance` but if i add the both deserializers (`TestClassDeserializer` and `TestClassDeserializerForInsideField`): jackson use only one - the first (`TestClassDeserializer`). And field deserializer is just skipped by jackson.

P.S.
here is my query for google from browser history (for better search)
`jackson convert any string to int`, `jackson trim string to int`, `JsonDeserializer trim symbols int text whitespace`

Comment: Jackson version?

Comment: @DiegoBorba 2.9.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```java
TestClass testClass = mapper2.readValue("\"5 ttt\"", TestClass.class);
```

By adding double quotes around the input string, like this: `"5 ttt"`, you **explicitly indicate to Jackson that the value should be treated as a string**.

**NOTE**:

If you have any string value and you want it to wrap with quotes, than  you must use `writeValueAsString` ***carefully***.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    String value = "hello";

    value = wrap(value);

    assert "\"hello\"".equals(value);

    value = "\"hello test 2 with quotes\"";

    value = wrap(value);

    assert "\"hello test 2 with quotes\"".equals(value);
}

private static String wrap(final String value) throws JsonProcessingException {
    if (!isQuotedString(value)) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(value);
    }
    return value;
}

private static boolean isQuotedString(Object value) {
    if (value instanceof String) {
        String stringValue = (String) value;
        return stringValue.startsWith("\"") && stringValue.endsWith("\"");
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you don't check if the string already have quotes, it **will result in additional quotes around old quotes**, and that wrong!

Comment: Just the public field would be enough but an ugly bean :-)

Comment: Thanks, i mean something else in post, update it

Comment: Thanks, i update my question with your suggestion but it does not work...

Answer (score 0):

Here, you need to convert your given string using `writeValueAsString` method and pass that string into the `readValue` method as shown below:

**Code:**

```
 public class Abc {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper2 = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = mapper2.writeValueAsString("5 ttt");
        TestClass testClass = mapper2.readValue(json, TestClass.class);
        System.out.println(testClass.field);
    }

    public static class TestClass {

        public String field;

        public TestClass(){}

        public TestClass(String field) {
            this.field = field;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
5 ttt
```

***Note:*** Incase we are using parameterised constructor, we need to add a default constructor explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, i mean something else in post, update it

Comment: @BestowsInConstructing okay, I got your problem, i have updated my code accordingly.

Comment: @BestowsInConstructing you can try with this approach, No need to add any custom deserialiser here.

Comment: @BestowsInConstructing Have you tried it this way?

Comment: No, writeValueAsString - not what anyone must need here! Cause if you already have quotes in string, it will surround value with additional quotes, for example, if we have `"hello world"` than writeValueAsString will return `"\"hello world\""`. You must check if value already has quotes and than add them